# Make Ubuntu run like a new installation again without reinstalling?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I want to remove all the apps I have manually installed & erase all the configurations I have made. Just like in case I want to give my computer to somebody else.. How can I do it while **preserving** personal files in **Home**?

Answer (score 2):

Goto **Synaptic Package Manager** > Click **Status** Button > choose **Installed (Manual)** from the left side list. Then you will get all the packages you have manually installed. Select them all and remove.

[image]

Comment: And ***be very careful if you do this!***  It is entirely possible you will break things if you're not careful with what you remove!

Comment: would you let me know how to select all ?

Comment: Select the first package. Goto the last package, hold SHIFT key and click on the last